# str_extract_all not listing all possible matches (R, stringr)

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

**Setting the Scene**

I have this string:

```
string <- "Apples/Bananas/Grapes/"
```

I am trying to find all possible substring matches with this list:

```
pattern <- "Apples/Bananas/|Bananas/Grapes/|Grapes/|Grapes/Pears/"
```

The expected output is:

```
"Apples/Bananas/" "Bananas/Grapes/" "Grapes/"
```

**What I have tried**

I tried using str_extract_all:

```
matches <- str_extract_all(string, pattern)
```

but I am only getting

```
"Apples/Bananas/" "Grapes/"
```

Why is it not returning "Bananas/Grapes/"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a vector of strings you want to extract:

```r
library(stringr)

string <- "Apples/Bananas/Grapes/"

pattern <- c("Apples/Bananas/", "Bananas/Grapes/", "Grapes/", "Grapes/Pears/")

unlist(str_match_all(string, pattern))

#> [1] "Apples/Bananas/" "Bananas/Grapes/" "Grapes/"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Peter!  This is exactly what I needed. ChatGPT was absolutely useless when I asked it.

Comment: You are better off reading the package documentation with: `?str_extract_all()` or searching directly in Stack Overflow. There's nothing intelligent about AI: it's just clever statistics and machine learning.

Comment: @Peter, great solution, great that you can pass vectors to `stringr::str_extract_all()`. Just wondering why OP's try didn't work. It seems because `Apples/Bananas` was already matched, `Bananas/Grapes/` does not match anymore, as if the Bananas were removed from the string. Is there a regex way to make this behavior different?

Comment: I'm guessing that it may be due to the order of processing the OR elements in the pattern string. Once the pattern "Apples/Bananas/" is extracted the regex search does not start at the beginning of the string to test for other OR elements to extract. But to be honest this is beyond my current understanding of regex so may not be a correct interpretation.

Comment: @Peter, thanks! It sounds like a logical explanation, I'll do some more research :)

Answer (score 1):

With your original character string using `strsplit` and `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)

unlist(str_extract_all(string, unlist(strsplit(pattern, "\\|"))))
[1] "Apples/Bananas/" "Bananas/Grapes/" "Grapes/"
```

Comment: Thank you Andre! I already marked Peter's answer as correct, but this also worked